# Transform a div with translateX 100% then push it back into view by x amount of pixels

Tags: jquery, html, css, transform

I am trying to make my own push navigation and I am using translateX to push the content to the right hand side to reveal the navigation.

The problem I am having is that I don't want the content to be pushed 100% to the right and have a small portion of it showing on the right hand side.

I can't specify the exact amount of pixels because it needs to be responsive. What I thought I could do was translateX it to 100% and then somehow pull it back by say 50px but I can't figure out how to do this.

```js
$(document).on('click','.wrapper span', function() {
  $('.wrapper').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
.wrapper {
  background:red;
  height:100%;
}
.wrapper span {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:yellow;
}
.wrapper.active {
  transform:translateX(100%);
}
.navigation {
  position:absolute;
  background:#666666;
  color:#ffffff;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  i am a wrapper
  <span>click me</span>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
  i am a nav
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/rbkqagog/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `calc` for this? (Browser breakdown support [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc))

Relevant code:

```
.wrapper.active {
  transform:translateX( calc(100% - 50px) );
}
```

Full example below:

```js
$(document).on('click','.wrapper span', function() {
  $('.wrapper').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
.wrapper {
  background:red;
  height:100%;
}
.wrapper span {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:yellow;
}
.wrapper.active {
  transform:translateX( calc(100% - 50px) );
}
.navigation {
  position:absolute;
  background:#666666;
  color:#ffffff;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  i am a wrapper
  <span>click me</span>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
  i am a nav
</div>
```

You can also chain transforms together like this:

```
.wrapper.active {
  transform:translateX(100%) translateX(-50px);
}
```

Full example of this method:

```js
$(document).on('click','.wrapper span', function() {
  $('.wrapper').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
.wrapper {
  background:red;
  height:100%;
}
.wrapper span {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:yellow;
}
.wrapper.active {
  transform:translateX(100%) translateX(-50px);
}
.navigation {
  position:absolute;
  background:#666666;
  color:#ffffff;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  i am a wrapper
  <span>click me</span>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
  i am a nav
</div>
```

Comment: that's perfect! I didn't realise you could do this! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using negative margin is a really good trick

```
.wrapper.active{
  position: relative
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

EDIT

Without relative positioning

```
.wrapper.active{
  margin-left: calc(100% - 50px);
  margin-right: calc(-100% + 50px);
}
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.wrapper span', function() {
  $('.wrapper').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
.wrapper.active {
  margin-left: calc(100% - 50px);
  margin-right: calc(-100% + 50px);
}
.navigation {
  position: absolute;
  background: #666666;
  color: #ffffff;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  i am a wrapper
  <span>click me</span>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
  i am a nav
</div>
```

Comment: I added just added a snippet. It seems to work fine.

Comment: ahh ok, I've noticed it has a relative position on the .wrapper  , sorry I should have mentioned I wasn't using relative on my main project due to child divs being absolutely positioned against parents of the wrapper.  But yes it does work in this context. Thanks

Comment: Still possible with margins, but translate might be a cleaner solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try it in jQuery using the hide and show logic. Initialise the menu and the content but on start (`document.ready()`) hide the menu then show it `onclick` like so

```
<div class="wrapper">
  i am a wrapper
  <span>click me</span>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
  i am a nav
</div>
```

The wrapper and navigation must be next to next starting with the navigation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navigation').hide();
    $('.wrapper').click(function() {
        $('.navigation').show(100);
    });    
});
```

This could do you some magic since you do not want the wrapper and navigation to divorce